# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{H^{(a)}_{n}}{n^b} = \zeta(a,b) + \zeta(a+b)$

Tags: riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers

I've come across the formula:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{H^{(a)}_{n}}{n^b} = \zeta(a,b) + \zeta(a+b)$$

where  $H^{(a)}_{n}$ is the [Generalized Harmonic nuber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalizations) and $\zeta(a,b)$ is the [Multiple zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function#Two_parameters_case).

I have no idea if this identity is true, and if yes then how to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this formula ? It would be interesting to know.

Comment: I think I know which identity you are referring to, it's the one from the Euler sums article which I sent you, right? Are you referring to the symmetry relation there?

Comment: Now that @ClaudeLeibovici has kindly shown your conjecture to be false, do you want to rephrase the question (with the aim of finding a true identity) or accept his disproof as the answer to your question.

Comment: @JamesArathoon. Thanks for such a comment. I already knew that you are a very fair-play user. Once more, a proof of it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Sorry I retract the above comment. Easy mistake to make when $\zeta(a,b)$ can stand for more than one function.  Ali Shadhar is correct in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$f(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{H^{(a)}_{n}}{n^b} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(a,b)=\zeta(a,b) + \zeta(a+b)$$ I just computed a few values  and it does not seem to work
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & f(a,b) & g(a,b) \\
 6 & 5 & 1.03751 & 1.00060 \\
 6 & 4 & 1.08364 & 1.00134 \\
 6 & 3 & 1.20533 & 1.00373 \\
 6 & 2 & 1.65564 & 1.02142 \\
 5 & 4 & 1.08499 & 1.00357 \\
 5 & 3 & 1.20874 & 1.00976 \\
 5 & 2 & 1.66710 & 1.04528 \\
 4 & 3 & 1.21585 & 1.02817 \\
 4 & 2 & 1.69187 & 1.09967 \\
 3 & 2 & 1.74849 & 1.23898 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I see, there's something wrong with my question then, sorry

Comment: The identity is right. Make sure you write $\zeta(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{(n+1)^b}$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you provided, we have $$\zeta(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{(n+1)^b}$$

Let the index start from zero since $H_0^{(a)}=0$,

$$\zeta(a,b)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{(n+1)^b}$$

Shift the index,

$$\zeta(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}^{(a)}}{n^b}$$

Use $H_{n-1}^{(a)}=H_n^{(a)}-\frac1{n^a}$,

$$\zeta(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{n^b}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{a+b}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{n^b}-\zeta(a+b)$$

or

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{H^{(a)}_{n}}{n^b} = \zeta(a,b) + \zeta(a+b).$$